# Cloning a Git repo without the .git directory

Tags: git, git-clone

Is it possible to clone a repository without git creating a .git folder inside the local copy of the repository?  Sort of like a read only functionality?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You’re looking for [`git archive`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html). You either use it within a repository, or pass it the `--remote=<URL>` switch, and it gives you a tarball or zip file of the source tree. You can pipe that straight back into `tar` if you want to just get a pristine copy of the tree.

Comment: `git archive` can also create archives from remote repository.  See the `--remote` option.

Comment: @lunaryorn: Sounds like you have the real answer - if you posted it, I'd certainly upvote it.

Comment: @lunaryorn: That must have gotten added while I wasn’t looking. Thanks for the pointer. I’ve updated my answer.